# Using REST for CRUD operations in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, rest, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying do CRUD operations on Azure Cosmos DB using REST. As per the link-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/create-a-document
I have created my payload and trying to test it using Restman in Opera browser. Below is my payload details-

**Headers**

```
Authorization       ***************************

Content-Type        application/query+json

x-ms-date           Tue, 05 Dec 2017 16:49:31 GMT

x-ms-session-token  Session

x-ms-version        2017-02-22
```

**Body**

```
id        sg4c828f-31f8-4db4-8e7c-e8bdff222dsg

value     {     "id": "AndersenFamily",     "LastName": "Andersen",     "Parents": [       {         "FamilyName": null,         "FirstName": "Thomas"       },       {         "FamilyName": null,         "FirstName": "Mary Kay"       }     ],     "Children": [       {         "FamilyName": null,         "FirstName": "Henriette Thaulow",         "Gender": "female",         "Grade": 5,         "Pets": [           {             "GivenName": "Fluffy"           }         ]       }     ],     "Address": {       "State": "WA",       "County": "King",       "City": "Seattle"     },     "IsRegistered": true   }
```

The auth-token which is put in the request header has been generated in C# using below code (as per the sample in the link mentioned above)-

```
string GenerateAuthToken(string verb, string resourceType, string resourceId, string date, string key, string keyType, string tokenVersion)
{
    var hmacSha256 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 { Key = Convert.FromBase64String(key) };

    verb = verb ?? "";
    resourceType = resourceType ?? "";
    resourceId = resourceId ?? "";

    string payLoad = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n",
            verb.ToLowerInvariant(),
            resourceType.ToLowerInvariant(),
            resourceId,
            date.ToLowerInvariant(),
            ""
    );

    byte[] hashPayLoad = hmacSha256.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payLoad));
    string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hashPayLoad);

    return System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "type={0}&ver={1}&sig={2}",
        keyType,
        tokenVersion,
        signature));
}
```

This is how pass the parameters-

```
GenerateAuthToken("GET", "dbs", "dbs/ToDoList", "Tue, 05 Dec 2017 16:49:31 GMT", PARENT_KEY, "master", "1.0");
```

So when I make the POST request to the URL-

```
https://<account_name>.documents.azure.com:<port>/dbs/DCEAAA==/colls/DCEAAIcEVAA=/docs
```

I get below response-

> {
>       "code": "Unauthorized",
>       "message": "The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol,
>   and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to
>   sign: 'post\ndocs\ndceaaicevaa=\ntue, 05 dec 2017 16:49:31
>   gmt\n\n'\r\nActivityId: 7565996c-d008-438d-a1e9-744d4871948a,
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.19.121.4" }

I am clueless what exactly is going wrong here. Please let me know if someone have any ideas. For any clarifications please let me know.

**Edit:** Adding the Restman screenshot below-
[image]

Comment: One thing I noticed here is that the parameters passed to `GenerateAuthToken` are not the same as you're passing in the request. For example, verb is `GET` in that method but you're actually making a `POST` request. Could that be the reason?

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks for reply. Actually that's what I saw in the sample and I think it is just for generating the auth-token. I tried using POST but that doesn't work too.

Comment: Can you please edit your post and put the actual values you used?

Comment: @GauravMantri Except the auth key and POST URL all other values are actual.

Comment: Again, the issue is the resource type in `GenerateAuthToken` is `dbs` but the resource type in your request is `docs`. Please ensure that the values provided to this method is same as your request.

Comment: @GauravMantri I tried by passing `docs` in the parameter but same issue. Here is the link- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/create-a-document The POST URL they have mentioned here is how I am doing.

Comment: IMHO, It's very hard to figure out what exactly is wrong when the code in question is not the same as the one you're actually using. Please edit your question and include the actual code and the latest error message you're getting.

Comment: @GauravMantri The only code I am using is for generating the auth token (in C#) which I picked up from here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/access-control-on-documentdb-resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN exactly the same without modification and there is no other code which I have to show.

Comment: With all due respect, why it is so hard for you to edit your question and include the actual values and error message? We're going round and round over the same thing. I am pretty sure that there's slight value mismatch because of which you're getting this error.

Comment: @GauravMantri I can't include the auth-token/auth-key and POST URL (with account name). Rest all I have included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I follow up you mentioned Document Create Document API, and do a demo to create documentdb document with rest API. You could refer to it. For other operates you could follow the following code and construct the hashed token.

According to the [Common Azure Cosmos DB REST request headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/common-documentdb-rest-request-headers), if we want to create a document we need to prepare the Header as following

```
Authorization,x-ms-date,Content-Type,x-ms-version
```

We could get the x-m-version from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/). The latest version is  **2017-02-22**.

We could get the demo code you mentioned from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/access-control-on-documentdb-resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN),about how to constructing the hashed token signature for a master token please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/access-control-on-documentdb-resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN). From the document we could know that resourceType could be  `"dbs", "colls", "docs".` We need to **create a document**, so **resourceType = docs**

```
var databaseId = "databaseName";
var collectionId = "collectionName";
var datetime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R");
var verb = "post";
var resourceType = "docs"; //
var resourceId = $"dbs/{databaseId}/colls/{collectionId}";
var mastKey = "mastkey value";
var keyType = "master";
var tokenVersion = "1.0";
var authToken = GenerateAuthToken(verb, resourceType, resourceId, datetime, mastKey, keyType, tokenVersion);
```

We also need to get the **x-ms-date** value from the above mentioned code varible **datetime**

[image]

```
Post https://{documentDBAccount}.documents.azure.com:443/dbs/{databaseName}/colls/{collectionId}/docs
```

[image]

**Update:**

Please use the following data as json body

```
{
    "id": "sg4c828f-31f8-4db4-8e7c-e8bdff222dsg",
    "value": {
        "id": "AndersenFamily",
        "LastName": "Andersen",
        "Parents": [
            {
                "FamilyName": null,
                "FirstName": "Thomas"
            },
            {
                "FamilyName": null,
                "FirstName": "Mary Kay"
            }
        ],
        "Children": [
            {
                "FamilyName": null,
                "FirstName": "Henriette Thaulow",
                "Gender": "female",
                "Grade": 5,
                "Pets": [
                    {
                        "GivenName": "Fluffy"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Address": {
            "State": "WA",
            "County": "King",
            "City": "Seattle"
        },
        "IsRegistered": true
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. Looks like you made it working. I will get back to you once I try it out.

Comment: My Collection name is ToDoList. How do I get the databaseID and collectionID? And how do I construct the POST URL?

Comment: OK I figured out the databaseID and collectionID from an existing record's value- `"_self": "dbs/DCEAAA==/colls/DCEAAIcEVAA=/docs/DCEAAIcEVAAHAAAAAAAAAA==/",` So my databaseID is `DCEAAA==` and collectionID is `DCEAAIcEVAA=`

Comment: I test it just with database name and collection name. Detail info you refer to the screenshot

Comment: I tried with the database name and collection name. Now it gives error 400 bad request and says the request payload is invalid.

Comment: 400 error means that client data error. What do you body like ? Does it RAW json format?

Comment: I posted it in the question above under Body. Can you check if that is valid?

Comment: I have updated the answer with json format body with you mentioned body. Details please refer to the updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160571/discussion-between-tom-sun-and-souvik-ghosh).