# How to connect coldfusion with azure cosmos db

Tags: coldfusion, azure-cosmosdb, coldfusion-2016

We have an application developed with coldfusion. We want to use cosmos database as backend. Please help me with this.

Comment: Have you accessed a No-SQL DB before? There's a JAVA SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/cosmosdb?view=azure-java-stable

Comment: I was going to suggest using a JDBC driver, but looks like there [isn't a jdbc driver yet](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/17788768-jdbc-support) (at least not a free one), which was surprising.

Comment: @Ageax I guess this has to do with the way these types of datastores work. You have no fixed structure (columns)

Comment: Can we do it with azure cosmos rest api ?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler - That makes sense. There is an odbc driver, but it mentions the data is "flattened" somehow.  I also come across a commercial jdbc driver, but now I'm thinking it probably "flattens" the data too.

Comment: @Sachan Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Cosmos DB is No-SQL database like MongoDB which doesn't have a JDBC driver. So please do not treat it the same as a relational database.

Now, [Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/introduction) has several quickstarts. These are the SDK options:

[image: Screen shot of Quickstarts]

However, it also supports [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/) to satisfy any development languages, as long as you can build an http request. You can refer to these two REST samples:

1. [Using REST for CRUD operations in Azure Cosmos DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47659609/using-rest-for-crud-operations-in-azure-cosmos-db)
2. [How do I generate the rest authorization token for cosmos db in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713990/how-do-i-generate-the-rest-authorization-token-for-cosmos-db-in-python/49729111#49729111)

BTW,the most important thing in Cosmos DB REST API is the `authorization` header. Please refer to this detailed [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/access-control-on-cosmosdb-resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Answer (score 0):

Cosmos DB is accessed by an API, so it is possible to write a interface for Cosmos DB to make it easier to use it as a data source.

I've written a little demo for this: https://github.com/dominicr/CFCosmosDB